# Maven dependency on another Maven project

Tags: linux, maven-2, pom.xml, maven-dependency-plugin, aerospike

I'm currently having trouble trying to add add the dependency of another Maven project (specifically Aerospike) into my project.  I already did a `mvn install` on the Aerospike project so in my repository (on Linux: ~/.m2/repository/com/aerospike/aerospike-client/3.0.6) I see a aerospike-client-3.0.6.jar.lastUpdated file.  However, when I add the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aerospike</groupId>
    <artifactId>aerospike-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

into my project and perform an `mvn install`, it returns this error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building in-memory database poc 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.aerospike:aerospike-client:jar:3.0.6 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.601s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Aug 16 11:49:43 EDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/954M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project: Could not resolve dependencies for project: Failure to find com.aerospike:aerospike-client:jar:3.0.6 in http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jboss-public-repository-group has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you list/tree what you have in ~/.m2/repository/com/aerospike/aerospike-client/3.0.6 please. (on windows it's: C:\Users\<$USER>\.m2\...)

Comment: I have updated the question with the detailed repository location. thanks

Comment: "resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jboss-public-repository-group has elapsed or updates are forced" - have you tried forcing the updates? just add a -U when running from command line.

Comment: linski, thank you for your suggestion.  i tried it and i got the same error.

Comment: In a situation like this I usually manually delete the problematic version from the repo. But, I don't see any com/aerospike/aerospike-client folder in that repo https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/. How did you get that dependency?

Comment: The binary is not found in the repository.  I have the Maven project on my local machine and I build aerospike project with an "mvn install" which created the aerospike-client module.  How can I configure my pom.xml to add the aerospike-library into my own project at this point?  Thanks!

Comment: @ksdnlee any update on the matter?

Comment: @linski I have up'd your answer, it really helped a lot!  Thank you so much!

Comment: @ksdnlee np, glad to help. have you managed to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

The console output says that Maven is searching for `com.aerospike:aerospike` artifact in the [JBoss public repository](http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public) but that artifact isn't there.

```
Failure to find com.aerospike:aerospike-client:jar:3.0.6 in                                         
http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public
```

The OP stated that he installed it locally.

### Discussion

Maven is trying to download a locally installed artifact from a remote repository that does not have that artifact. [By default](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html) dependencies are first searched in local repository. AFAIK, the only thing that can override this behavior are the [artifact update policies](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories) defined in `settings.xml`.

AFAIK, the offline build ([`-o`](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html)) should override any such policies.
I tried to reproduce this situation by deleting dependencies from my local repo and intentionally declaring nonexistent dependencies and Maven acted as documented (offline build does not try to download). I have not played with update policies though.

### Solution

Following up on the comments, I have verified the offline build procedure in the following environment:

```
Apache Maven 3.1.0 
Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
OS name: "linux", version: "3.2.0-23-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

The offline build procedure in short:

- download all the online dependencies
- install all the offline dependencies
- run offline build

All the commands are run from the project root folder.

First, comment all the dependencies that are not found in any **remote** repository from your pom, e.g.:

```
<!--
 <dependency>
        <groupId>does</groupId>
        <artifactId>not</artifactId>
        <version>exist</version>
 </dependency>
-->
```

Prepare the [offline build by downloading all the dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html):

```
mvn dependency:go-offline
```

If you don't comment out the missing dependencies this goal will fail. You can verify it by observing that Maven has **successfully** downloaded all the artifacts in your console output.

Next, install the missing dependencies [manually in your local repo](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<PATH_TO_MISSING_DEP_JAR_FILE> 
                         -DgroupId=does  
                         -DartifactId=not   
                         -Dversion=exist 
                         -Dpackaging=jar
```

That will produce `not-exist.jar` (a copy of <PATH_TO_MISSING_DEP_JAR_FILE>) and `not-exist.pom` along with metadata files in your local repository under `<LOCAL_REPO_PATH>/.m2/repository/does/not/exist/`

**Verify** that those files exist under that exact directory structure.
Default locations of your local repository for different platforms are [here](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/where-is-maven-local-repository/), but if it isn't there, then run:

```
mvn help:effective-settings > settings.log
```

which will dump the [interpolated settings](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-settings-mojo.html) for your project to `settings.log` file. Open it with a text editor and [read the path of your local repo](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html) under:

```
<settings>
  ...
  <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo/</localRepository>
  ...
</settings>
```

Now you can run your build in offline mode:

```
mvn clean install -o
```

You can set [offline mode in your settings file](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Simple_Values) also, but that will set offline mode for [a specified user or system-wide](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Introduction) as opposed to command line switch which is per project when you want it.

### Conclusion

**Carefully** run this procedure **exactly as described**, and if you still can't build your project, then please run:

```
mvn help:effective-pom > pom.log
mvn help:effective-settings > settings.log
```

and post the contents of `pom.log` and `settings.log` files here.

Comment: interesting. 1) have you tried the -o switch? 2) what does mvn -version output?

Comment: I have tried the -o and -U switch and I get the same error.  The mvn -version output is 
`Apache Maven 3.1.0 (893ca28a1da9d5f51ac03827af98bb730128f9f2; 2013-06-27 22:15:3
2-0400)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.1.0
Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.39-400.17.1.el6uek.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"`
I tried commenting out the repository and it just started searching from another repository.  Is there a way to force Maven to search in its local repository?

Comment: yes, by using -o switch. I just verified that, I deleted a dep from my project and ran it with -o switch, and the build failed. Without it suceeded. I have Maven 3.0.4. There is another way maybe, just a sec

Comment: It seems that even with the -o switch it is still searching for the .jar file in the jboss repository.  Thank you linski so much for your help!

Comment: Uh I'm done for today, my version is older than yours :)). I'll try it tommorrow morning if no one answers it, good luck until then.